# Can one make a virtual midi device with the web midi api?

Tags: web-midi

The web MIDI API currently allows developers to access MIDI devices and send events to them. This means we can create a webpage that sends MIDI messages to and from MIDI devices of our choosing.

I'm looking to create three types of pages:

- virtual MIDI keyboard
- virtual MIDI synthesizer
- virtual MIDI cables/plugs

I'm looking to do this so that users can just open and play different keyboards with different synths, all through a standard form of communication (MIDI, and the web MIDI API). They could even change the connection management they want to use. If the web MIDI API supports it, they could use a mix of virtual web MIDI devices, virtual desktop MIDI devices, and real MIDI devices.

However, I can't find a way to create a virtual device of my own. Is there a way to create such a device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid this just isn't supported yet.  It's been filed as a potential feature request - https://github.com/WebAudio/web-midi-api/issues/45 - I'd encourage you to add your support and scenarios there.